# I want to write a number, then make an operation (if N is even,then N/2, or if N is odd,then (N*3) +1) and do it until the new number is equal to 1

Tags: loops, while-loop, integer, conditional-statements

I wanna make an algorithm that can take a number that I write and then make an operation, then take the answer, and repeat with the new number until the number is equal to 1

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Nombres {

   public static void main(String args[]) {
      int amount;
      Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

      System.out.print("Inscrivez un nombre");
      amount = keyboard.nextInt();

      while (amount != 1) {

         if (amount % 2 > 0) {
            System.out.println((amount * 3) + 1);
         }
         if (amount % 2 == 0) {
            System.out.println(amount / 2);
         }
         if (amount == 1) {
            System.out.println("FIN");
         }
      }
      if (amount == 1) {
         System.out.println("1 FIN");
      }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You do not change `amount` on each iterarion. E.g.

```
if (amount % 2 == 0)
    amount = amount / 2;
else
    amount = amount * 3 + 1

System.out.println(amount);
```